# Dataframe header by concatenating rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given this example dataframe in Pandas

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'],
                    'b' : ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'x'],
                    'c' : ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu']})
```

looking like

```
       a  b    c
0    one  x  abc
1    two  y  def
2  three  y  ghi
3   four  x  jkl
4   five  y  mno
5    six  x  pqr
6  seven  x  stu
```

I would like to build a new by concatenating e.g. rows 2 & 3 to get something like

```
   two_three y_y def_ghi
0    one     x   abc
1    two     y   def
2  three     y   ghi
3   four     x   jkl
4   five     y   mno
5    six     x   pqr
6  seven     x   stu
```

Any idea for a vector-like realization?

Thanks a lot, Sascha

Answer (score 2):

You can get desired result applying `str.join` along axis to a dataframe slice. See for example

```
>>> df.iloc[[1,2]].apply('_'.join, axis=0)
two_three    two_three
y_y                y_y
def_ghi        def_ghi
dtype: object
```

If you want to name your columns this way, just do

```
>>> df.columns = df.iloc[[1,2]].apply('_'.join, axis=0)
>>> df
  two_three y_y def_ghi
0       one   x     abc
1       two   y     def
2     three   y     ghi
3      four   x     jkl
4      five   y     mno
5       six   x     pqr
6     seven   x     stu

[7 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Hmm, another Problem popped up now  since my data is coming from a file I set all columns to "dtype=object" via read_csv and replaced all nA's with 
    df = df.fillna('')
But now the .join results in unicode-strings for the Header
    u'two_three ' etc. 
So how to get rid of this?